# MYSQL SELECT WHERE CLAUSE - exclude rows

Tags: mysql, sql

In MYSQL, let's say I have following two tables.

"orders":

```
id   |    name    | customer_id |    type   |  id_fabric
--------------------------------------------------------
1    | "P1601"    |      0      |     1     |    1    
2    | "M6451"    |      0      |     2     |    2    
3    | "T8200"    |      8      |     1     |    1    
4    | "R7441"    |      0      |     2     |    2    
5    | "S8018"    |      2      |     1     |    3    
6    | "P1240"    |      7      |     1     |    3
```

"fabrics":

```
id    |  color  |  remaining 
----------------------------
1     | black   |  3.40 
2     | red     |  16 
3     | navy    |  12
```

I would like to create a query to retrieve only the fabrics whose remaining is greater than 5, which don't have any orders with `customer_id = 0` of and whose order type is not equal to 2

So in this case the result would be:

```
id  | color   |  remaining
------------------------------------------------
3   | navy    |  12
```

I've tried to achieve this by using this following Sql query, but it doesn't get the expected result:

```
SELECT
    color,
    remaining
FROM
    fabrics
LEFT JOIN orders ON id_fabric = id
WHERE
    remaining > 2 AND id IN(
    SELECT
        id_fabric
    FROM
        orders
    WHERE
        type != 2 AND customer_id != 0
)
GROUP BY
    id
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Not sure why PHP tag is here. This most likely only Mysql problem

Answer (score 2):

Use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT
    f.color,
    f.remaining
FROM fabrics f
WHERE f.remaining > 5 AND 
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM orders o
        WHERE o.id_fabric = f.id AND
              o.type = 2 AND o.customer_id = 0
    )
```

Note that also JOIN and GROUP BY can be omitted from your original query.

Comment: Please update the answer to fix the syntax errors. Missing `AND` in the subquery criteria, as well as remove  `id` in `id NOT EXISTS`

Comment: I interpete the question a litle different I think the last condition should be `AND (o.type = 2 OR o.customer_id = 0)` but is OP to decide which one

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I did as well, however the OP specifically said `and whose` and did not qualify the condition of including/excluding those orders in the example. *customer_id = 0 of and whose order type is not equal to 2*

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
SELECT
    color,
    remaining
FROM
    fabrics
 JOIN orders ON id_fabric = id
where customer_id!=0 and remaining>5 and type!=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `JOIN` and `WHERE` condition and 'GROUP BY`

`id` is same filed in both tables so use the alies name for tables.

```
select f.id,f.color,f.remaining
from fabrics f
join orders o on o.id_fabric  = f.id
where f.remaining > 2 and o.type !=2 and o.customer_id!=0
group by f.id
```

Comment: To ensure desired results, you should move the criteria for the order table, from the `WHERE` to the `JOIN ON`. Like `INNER JOIN orders AS o
ON o.id_fabric = f.id
AND o.customer_id != 0 
AND o.type != 2`  Also you would need to specify either `ANY_VALUE()` or an aggregate function when using [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) to avoid the MySQL 5.7+ `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that subselect in your where condition is necessary in this case.
You could simply go ahead like

```
SELECT
    color,
    remaining
FROM
    fabrics
LEFT JOIN orders ON id_fabric = id
WHERE
    remaining > 2  
    AND customer_id!=0
    AND type != 0
GROUP BY
    id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using correlated subquery

```
SELECT
    color,
    remaining
FROM
    fabrics
LEFT JOIN orders ON id_fabric = id where remaining > 5 and 
not exists (select 1 from orders o where o.id_fabric=fabrics.id and o.customer_id=0 and o.type=2)
```

Comment: Since orders appears to be a Many (orders) to One (fabric) relationship and not One-to-One, this would produce multiple rows of the same fabric, based on the number of orders made of a fabric that matches the criteria.